# Multiple forms with shared values in jsp?

Tags: forms, jsp, button

So I need to make a page that contains some values(Surname, last name and city)

And I have 3 buttons - Insert , Update and Delete

My question to you is, how to create 3 submit buttons in the same form but having them go to different page if clicked and also send the values to the page

Can Forms share fields or something?

I know I could make 3 forms with the same code inside each, but it seems like a bad idea for a bigger project

Thanks For Helping :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have 1 form and the 3 buttons are normal ones (not submit). All the buttons call a the same javascript function like process('insert'), process('update') etc.

The javascript process function look a bit like

```
function process(kind) {

    var myform = document.getElementById('myform');

    if (kind === 'insert' ) {
      myform.setAttribute('action', '/insert');
    }
    else if (kind === 'update' ) {
      myform.setAttribute('action', '/update');
    }
    else {
       // etc.....
    }

    myform.submit();

}
```

In my option you should only have 2 buttons (Save, Delete) and in the back end you check if it's an insert or update by checking if the record already exists (for instance the id submitted was not empty)